# Start Android Activity with NFC without using Android Application Data

Tags: android, android-activity, tags, nfc, android-applicationrecord

I want an `NFC` tag to start certain Activity of my app and read an `ID`.

Now the applications writes a tag with one message and two records: the first Record contains the `AAR` and the second record contains a `TNF_EXTERNAL_TYPE` with an `ID` number:

[image]

That would work perfectly, BUT the problem is that I have `Ultralight NFC Chips` that only allow `64 bytes`, so I can't write both the `AAR` and the external type in the tag, just one of them.

The question is, is there a simple solution (apart of buying new `NTAG203` tags with more capacity) to start the application when reading my tags?

Answer (score 0):

You have to register an intent-filter for your app to be fired when an tag with the specific data is read.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use a URL with a custom scheme. That way you don't need the AAR record.

If the URL looks like:

```
et42://id/5547
```

Then you can create an intent-filter that specifically filters for the URL scheme `et42`, which is specific to your app. Android will always launch your app (unless another app filters for the same URL scheme).

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TAG_DISCOVERED" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:scheme="et42" />
</intent-filter>
```

I can't tell for sure. But that approach uses messages that are more likely to fit into 64 bytes. And it might work with other operating systems as well.